# find partial derivative of $a_1x+b_1y$ with respect to $a_2x+b_2y$

Tags: partial-derivative

What is the partial derivative of $a_1x+b_1y$ with respect to $a_2x+b_2y$?

$$\frac\partial{\partial (a_2x+b_2y)}(a_1x+b_1y)$$It is zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It is not, since the two expressions are not independent.

Say $f=a_2x+b_2y$ and $g=a_1x+b_1y$.

So, the problem now becomes,
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial f}$$
$$= \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial f} +  \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\cdot \frac{\partial y}{\partial f}$$
$$= \frac{a_1}{a_2}+\frac{b_1}{b_2}$$

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have another question on this concept. can you please help me with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2294824/understanding-partial-derivatives-in-backpropagation-algorithm