# find partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let
\begin{align}x&=at\\
y&=bt\\
z&=y^2\end{align}

Then $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = ?$$

I solved this as

\begin{align}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} &= 2y\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\\\\
&= 2y\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial x}\right)\\\\
&= 2y\times b\times \frac 1a\end{align}

Is this correct?

In this case are $z$ and $x$ independent or dependent variables?

EDIT
If this is correct and the derivative is non zero, then $z$ and $x$ are dependent variable. Can you help me solve this bigger problem [understanding partial derivatives in backpropagation algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2294824/understanding-partial-derivatives-in-backpropagation-algorithm)

Comment: Just to check your answer note that $z=y^2=b^2t^2=\frac{b^2}{a^2}x^2$ so that $z_x=\frac{2b^2x}{a^2}$.

Comment: ... this agrees with your answer by the way.

Answer (score 3):

actually x, y, z all are in parametric form in t 

but you can write z in term of x 
therefore z and x are dependent variable 
because if they are independent 
then the partial derivative of z with respect to x must be zero